# Copy data from tables in one db to duplicate tables in another db - What's the SQL?

Tags: sql, copy

I have a situation where I have 20 Access databases.  Each has the same 15 tables, but with different data.  (The name and schema is identical for each table across the 20 databases).

I want to make a new database with the same structure, and populate it with the contents of all of the 20 original databases, so I have one database with 15 big tables instead of 20 databases with 15 smaller tables.

I have to do it all in SQL, as I'm interfacing via this Ruby Acess library - http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html

Can anyone help me out with the SQL?  All I really need I think is an example of appending all the records from one table in a source db to one table in a destination db.

Oh and to make things a little more complicated, each of the fifteen tables in each db has a different set of fields, and some have a lot of fields (40 or so).  So, the perfect lazy solution would not require me to list every field in the table when I copy the rows across.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic sql would be a ["insert into select"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861.aspx) statement. To make it shorter I'll call your 20 databases like DB1, DB2, .. DB20 and your "final" database DBFinal.

The lazy solution would requere getting field names from the master shema - its better to list the fields (asuming u can autogenerate the sql statements or use any from your aplication or ER diagrams)

### Logic:

1) create DBFinal, disable autoincrement for primary keys (so u can insert primary key values from DB1, DB2, ...
2) generate a select that selects all rows and columns for each table. like:

```
SELECT key, atrb1, atrb2 FROM table1
```

3) by using text-copy paste assemble a "insert into select" statement something like:

```
INSERT into DBFinal.user.table1 (key, atrb1, atrb2) SELECT key, atrb1, atrb2 FROM table1
```

4) 
If u got same key values in different databases (for different values) u need to change all primary - foreign key values so u dont get duplicates in the target database. I recommend adding a value (row count + 1 in DBFinal). 
INSERT into table1 (key, atrb1, atrb2) IN DBFinal 
SELECT key+9001, atrb1, atrb2 FROM table1

Comment: Thanks Erv - i ended up doing just this using the ruby interface.  It was a bit arsey as i had to basically do something like this

- get field names from source table
- get row data from source table
- use above to build up an INSERT INTO string

I'd already done the duplication-avoiding step by adding a product id field to each of the tables in every database (which was unique per database), and adding that to the composite primary key of each table.

cheers! max

Comment: Nice to hear you made it - it can be a though job demanding a lot of concentration (and hopefully no other "urgent tasks" interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL server available you could use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

With that you can use a GUI and wizards to transfer the data.

Comment: Hi Shiraz - i don't unfortunately, i need to do it all with sql.